# I lose some variables in Session when i go to a next page

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-framework-version

I have the problem. I rewrite code cause i need to change Oracle DB to Postgresql DB. I had good work code on .net Framework 4. For Postgresql i had to increase Framework 4 to Framework 4.5, because i have Nuget Npgsql package which works only from 4.5 Framework. I changed some lines

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("", new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString));
```

to

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("", new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString));
```

I left a few code without any changes for example

```
DbDataAdapter da = (DbDataAdapter)Session["MyConnection"];
DbDataReader ddr;
```

etc because it is an generic that have to work well in both cases.

But when i start Debugging and i change page after inintilization my Session
i have Error in this line

`da.Fill(dt);`
(dbDataAdapter da, DataTable dt)

Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

But i continue to see My session, its Id, some parametres like my name e.t.c but i have
SelectCommand.Connection NULL.

I tried to change my Redirects paths with "~"
`Response.Redirect("~/page.aspx")`
without "~"
`Response.Redirect("~/page.aspx");` 
full paths
`Response.Redirect("localhost:4025/page.aspx");`
I tried to increase verson of My nuget packages and Framework.

Nothing has not helped me.

Comment: Why you store the DataAdapter in the user session? That doesn't make sense and begs for issues

Comment: I rewrite this code, this is not mine.

Comment: If you rewrite this code, change it so that you don't store any database related stuff into the session. Always create the connection and all related objects where you need them, by using the `using`-statement to ensure that everything gets disposed properly even in case of an error. On that way your code becomes more performant and stable. The ADO.NET connection pool ensures that you don't really create new physical connections. Just don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That wil be better If i transfer String for connection in session instead the connection? Session["MyConn"] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["MyString"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Why you need to store the connection-string in the session? Has every user a different connection-string? Why you don't use a configuration file like web.config? That file is already cached, just in case that you think that you need to optimize it.

Comment: I thinked that works, I need use this. But ive understood you. This code has web.config and i will use it thanks.